# How to Beautify rss feed in django?

Tags: python, xml, django

I generate rss feed for my website using Django. I using below code for generate feed.

```
class getTenderfeeds(Feed):
     title = "Tender Links"
     link = "/rss-tender/"
     description = "Tender link feeds"

     def items(self):
         return CareerTenderCT.objects.order_by('-cart_created_datetime')[:3]

     def item_title(self, item):
         return item.cart_title

     def item_description(self, item):
         return item.cart_desc

     def item_link(self, item):
         return '/view/12/'+ item.cart_absolute_url
```

After that in url.py call this class.

```
url(r'^rss-tender/', getTenderfeeds()),
```

When i open this url the UI part is look like below image.

[image]

But i want to change beautify in xml, like below image.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is quite easy:

```
class CorrectMimeTypeFeed(DefaultFeed):
    content_type = 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'

class LatestEntriesFeed(Feed):
    feed_type = CorrectMimeTypeFeed
```

Django rssfeed class' default type is `application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8`

Change it, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I Created a html file in template directory and render all feed to that html like below code.

```
class getTenderfeeds(Feed):
    title = "Tender Links"
    link = "/rss-tender/"
    description = "Tender link feeds"

    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       try:
          obj = self.get_object(request, *args, **kwargs)
       except ObjectDoesNotExist:
          raise Http404('Feed object does not exist.')
       feedgen = self.get_feed(obj, request)
       response = HttpResponse(content_type=feedgen.content_type)
       if hasattr(self, 'item_pubdate') or hasattr(self, 'item_updateddate'):
          response['Last-Modified'] = http_date(
              timegm(feedgen.latest_post_date().utctimetuple()))
       feedgen.write(response, 'utf-8')
       response = re.sub(r'><', '>\n<', str(response))
       response = response.replace('Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8','')
       return render_to_response('html/feed/rss-tender.html',{ 'response':response,})

   def items(self):
       return CareerTenderCT.objects.order_by('-cart_created_datetime')[:3]

   def item_title(self, item):
       return item.cart_title

   def item_description(self, item):
       return item.cart_desc

   def item_link(self, item):
       return '/view/12/'+ item.cart_absolute_url
```